# Filtering Elasticsearch fields from index/store

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I was wondering what is the recommended approach to filter out some of the fields that are sent to Elasticsearch from Store and Index?

I want to filter our some fields from getting indexed in Elasticsearch. You may ask why you are sending them to Elasticsearch from the first place. Unfortunately, it is sent via another application that doesn't accept any filtering mechanism. Hence, filtering should be addressed at the time of indexing. Here is what we have done, but I am not sure what would be the consequences of these steps:

1- Disable dynamic mapping ("dynamic": "false" ) in ES templates.

2- Including only the required fields in _source and excluding the rest.

According to ES website, some of the ES functionalities will be disabled by disabling _source fields. Given I don't need the filtered fields at all, I was wondering whether the mentioned solution will break anything regarding the remaining fields or not?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mapping parameters that allow you to do what you want:

- [`index: true/false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html): if true the field value is indexed in order to be searched later on (default: true)
- [`store: true/false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html): if true the field values are stored in addition to being indexed. Usually, the field values are stored in the source already, but you can choose to not store the source but store the field value itself (default: false)
- [`enabled: true/false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html#enabled): only for the mapping type as a whole or for `object` types. you can decide whether to only store the value but not index it

So you can use any combination of the above parameters if you don't want to modify the source documents and simple let ES do it for you.

Comment: The problem is if I don't modify _source, it will maintain the original document in the _source. However, I just want to store/index specific fields. I don't want to apply any extra overhead what so ever to ES index due to the useless fields.

Comment: You might also want to check on [ingest processors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html), which have the ability to modify the source document before it gets indexed.

Comment: Remove processor is what I can use, but it is based on the list of what we want to remove, not what we want to maintain. I can write a custom processor, though.

Comment: I couldn't find any solution better than what I suggested in the question. I am using that right now.